# iOS5 application failing to install on iPad 1 and iPad 2

Tags: xcode4.3, ios5.1

I have application developed on xCode 4.3.1 with following build settings:

Architecture : standard (armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
Base SDK : iOS5
Build Active Architecture Only : NO
Valid Architectures : armv6 armv7

In info.plist, the Required Device Capabilities does not have any entry.

I am trying to install on iPad1, iPad 2 and latest iPad (3). The provisioning file has been created with all Device IDs included. The application Archive file (.ipa) file has been created with above build setting.

While the application gets installed on Latest iPad (3) successfully, on both other iPads (iPad 1 and iPad 2) I get " Failed to Install" message when sync through iTunes is attempted as per defined procedure.

Kindly help if any change in build setting is required. I have already tried setting Architecture to armv6 + armv7.

Comment: Just to confirm, both iPad1 and iPad2 are running iOS 5.1.1.